# Text and input element on same line with 100% input

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm wanting to create a form where the input and textarea elements fill the remaining space on the line but do not go to the next line. Here is my current (unworking) jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xz7uq18j/1/

thanks for any help

code:

```
 <div style="border: #000000 thin solid; text-align: left; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; width: 500px;">


Name: <input style="width: 100%"type="text" name="Name" value="Mr John Smith">
        Address:<textarea  style="width: 100%" name="Address" rows="6" cols="50">1 Road Street
        Town
        Postcode</textarea> <br>
        Primary Phone:<input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="PrimaryPhone" value="***"><br>
        Secondary Phone:<input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="SecondaryPhone" value="N/A"><br>
        Email Address:<input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="EmailAddress" value="N/A"><br>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the two elements you want together on one line in a div, and make that div a flex-box, with the `display:flex;` property in CSS.

```css
.one-line{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
 <div style="border: #000000 thin solid; text-align: left; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; width: 500px;">

<div class="one-line">
Name: <input style="width: 100%"type="text" name="Name" value="Mr John Smith">
        Address:<textarea  style="width: 100%" name="Address" rows="6" cols="50">1 Road Street
        Town
        Postcode</textarea>
</div> <br>
        Primary Phone:<input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="PrimaryPhone" value="***"><br>
        Secondary Phone:<input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="SecondaryPhone" value="N/A"><br>
        Email Address:<input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="EmailAddress" value="N/A"><br>
    </div>
```